# Android: avoiding passing activity to singletons by storing inside the Application class = memory leak?

Tags: java, android

I have a few singletons that require context information as they might have to show dialogs. Up until now I've passed the relevant contexts to the singletons, but this is increasingly leading to memory leaks. I was wondering whether storing a reference to the current activity inside the application class might be a way around this problem. Since the variable is overwritten everytime a new activity starts it shouldn't lead to a memory leak, but it's also accessible from all non-activity classes in the app.

Inside my application class:

```
private static Activity currentForegroundActivity;

public static void setCurrentlyVisibleActivity(Activity activity) {
    currentForegroundActivity = activity;
}

public static Activity getCurrentlyVisibleActivity() {
    return currentForegroundActivity;
}
```

Inside every activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    App.setCurrentlyVisibleActivity(this);
```

Inside every singleton:

```
methodThatRequiresUI(App.getCurrentlyVisibleActivity);
```

Are there any pitfalls going down this route that you can foresee? I suppose the application class might be cleared from memory by the OS, but if that happened the app itself would restart - it wouldn't lead to a null pointer. The get method might also get called during application startup before the set had been called - but I can write checks to get around that.

Comment: Do not store reference to activities (if really needed use WeekReference, but this is also bad idea). You will probably need to add one more parameter to singleton methods that needs reference to context.

Comment: "I have a few singletons that... might have to show dialogs" -- that's a bug, which you should fix.

Comment: never forget **keep it simple stupid**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Completely avoid using activity context to a singleton object
   that.(yeah you know this)
2. Dont inflate views, dialogs from app context. It will work but it
   will exclude styling and other stuff.

**Then how?**

1. make utility methods with static methods, pass context as
   parameter.
2. Use delegation (pass anonymous classes, or an
   interface)

Comment: I have the problem that some classes override methods that don't have context as an input parameter - for example, the google api login flow requires context information within various methods - I don't control when these methods are called nor can I add input parametersto them. If I can't pull the context information from the Application then I have to store it within the class, which is exactly what I want to avoid doing. Is there another way?

Comment: the activities may be destroyed and created and you OS will control it. Therefore you fave to save and restore your state with bundles,database,sharedprefs or files(json,xml,raw). You need to separate your context dependent logic from others. I don't know what you have done so far but maybe you can create separate manager classes for context dependent logic.If it is too late for you to change this, then you may try to clear your context on Destroy, and set in oncreate again. And there is many pitfalls awaiting you, outofmemory,nullpointers maybe even leaking windows